# Chef Pear Package * not found in either PEAR or PECL

Tags: pear, chef-infra

when using chef 11.4.0 on an ubuntu 10.04 with the php cookbook (version 1.2.2).  I am getting an error

RuntimeError: Package PEAR not found in either PEAR or PECL.

The relevant recipe code is as follows

```
php_pear "PEAR-drush" do
  package_name "PEAR"
  version "1.9.1"
  action :upgrade
end
```

I get this same error with any pear package I try to install.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Downgrading to the php cookbook 1.1.4 seems to solve the issue.  I tried a few of the later versions with the same problem.  So I don't know if there is something I am doing wrong or if it's simply a bug in the cookbook recipes.

Comment: Shouldn't it be working without "PEAR"? Like that: `php_pear "drush" do version "1.9.1" actiion :upgrade end`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to install a package named `PEAR`, which doesn't exist.

There are two ways to indicate to the `php_pear` resource which package to install. The first one (shorter) is by setting the resource `name` to the name of the package you want to install:

```
php_pear "drush" do # Set the package name here
  version "1.9.1"
  action :upgrade
end
```

And the second one is using the `package_name` attribute, like you're trying to do, but pointing it to the wrong package:

```
php_pear "install PEAR package drush" do
  package_name "drush" # Set the package name here
  version "1.9.1"
  action :upgrade
end
```

**Note:** The `php_pear` resource is case-*sensitive*, so make sure that the package name casing is correct.